# Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-studio

Сразу скажу, что в разработке моб. приложения я 0 но смог реализовать вэб приложение. Пытаюсь добавить в приложение функцию пушап уведомлений. Умные люди подсказали смотреть в сторону CGM https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/
Сгенерировал JSON файл для CGM, положил в проект, начал идти по шагам но на gradle затык.

Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Перерыл весь инет. У многих проблемы с нижними строками compile, но у меня именно с "Plugin". Как импортнуть этот плагин? Работаю в Android Studio.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "********"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 20
    versionName "1.20"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я ни разу этого не пробовал, но точно это строка нужна?.. Приведите ссылку на пример по коему вы gradle файл составили. И проверьте, что через SDKManager вы скачали все необходимые модули.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client?configured=true. А как проверить через SDK manager? Я в нем подключал что то когда то, знаю где он но как им выверять что не подключено их необходимого?

Comment: Я не нашёл там упоминания о строчке с плагином в gradle. Да и вообще про gradle. И на en-SO тоже в примерах этого не видел. Вы проверили SDKManager на предмет скачивания всего необходимого? И `buildToolsVersion` у вас устаревшие. В этом также, мб, проблема.

Comment: В SDKManager просто пробегитесь глазами по модулям помянутым в gradle. Но точно, думаю, нужны PlayServices всякие repository & support либы.

Comment: А это не та строчка? Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' или я не верно толковал?

Comment: Хм, может оно и надо... Добавьте в вопрос скриншот(ы) того, что у вас в SDKManager скачано. И обновите buildToolsVersion

Comment: Обновил всё что додумался и выложил скрин в первом посте.

Comment: У вас в dependencies выделены устаревшие версии. Попробуйте обновить их. И buildToolsVersion тоже. И студия у вас устаревшая. А в доках пишут, что всё должно быть последних версий.

Comment: Я по указанию предыдущего комментатора обновил это. На скрине это отразил. Теперь отразил и в самом тексте первого поста. Всё теперь соответствует тому что есть после обновления и ошибка всё еще есть. Мне на самом деле может проще все же сервис написать для проверки онлайн статуса через JSON? И не мучиться? Но говорят это сажает сильно девайс.

Comment: Ну, лично я всё ещё вижу в коде и на скриншоте старые версии библиотек и студии. Чтобы исключить возможность того, что не работает из-з этого, надо это всё обновить. Как ещё и что можно сделать вместо GCM я не знаю, т.к. ничем таким не пользовался.

Comment: Так. Я полный 0 в этом. Как обновить? Я же в SDK вкладке всё обновил что были использовано и что обновлялось.

Comment: Для начала обновите студию. Потом, в gradle файле наводите мышь на подсвеченные строки и выплывает подсказка, что либы устарели и нажмите альтЕнтер чтобы автоматом подставились последние значения версий.

Answer (score 6):

Пройдите к файлу `<your project folder>\build.gradle` и вы увидите что-то вроде этого:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Добавьте строку `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'` к этой штуке `dependencies { ... }`. Должно получиться что-то такое:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Это должно решить проблему.

*(Ps. не спутайте с файлом `<your project folder>\app\build.gradle`)*

Comment: Не пишите ответы на английском, пожалуйста.

Comment: I don't know Russian. :(

Comment: Use Google Translate at least . :)

Comment: Does it translate well to Russian? Because to my native language I can't understand half of what it translates, in the end neither languages can understand it. I will had a translation next to the sentences to please all people :)

Comment: Hmmm, was my post translated? It is showing up in Russian to me now.

Comment: It's better to answer in bad russian than in english in Ru SO. I've translated your answer.

Comment: Ah ok. For a moment I though my browser was messing with me. Thanks!

Comment: Для меня не сработало(